# Calculating rates

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Administrators at Massachusetts General Hospital believe that the hospital’s
expenditures $E(B)$, measured in dollars, are a function of how many beds $B$ are in use with $$E(B) = 14000 + (B +1)^2$$

On the other hand, the number of beds $B$ is a function of time $t$, measured in days, and is estimated that $$B(t) = 20\sin(\frac{t}{10} )+ 50$$

At what rate are the expenditures decreasing when $t = 100$ ?

I know the answer is $135$ dollars per day but I don't know how to get into that. I'm confused how it is decreasing. When I tried getting $E'(B(t))$ I got approximately $215$ which is wrong. Please help.

Comment: 0_o what kind of hospital expenditures are quadratic with respect to the number of beds, which are themselves sinusoidal as the days go on XD

Comment: I'm not sure. lol This may be unrealistic, however needs to be solved XD

Answer (score 1):

1. Substitute the function B(t) for B in the first equation. The result is:

   $E(t) = 14000 + (20sin(\frac{t}{10}) + 51)^2  $
2. Take the derivative of $E(t)$ using chain rule.

   $E'(t) = 4cos(\frac{t}{10})(20sin(\frac{t}{10}) + 51)$
3. Evaluate at $t = 100$ and round to receive your answer of $135$.

Answer (score 1):

What we want to find is $\frac{d}{dt}E(t)$, so I'll just get rid of the B(t) by substitution... it should be pretty easy here if we just plug in $B(t)$
$$E(t) = 14000 + \left(20\sin(\frac{t}{10} )+ 51\right)^2$$
We now just use the chain rule to simplify this a bit
$$E'(t) = 2\left(20\sin(\frac{t}{10} )+ 51\right)\frac{d}{dt}\left(20\sin(\frac{t}{10}\right)$$
$$= 4\cos\left(\frac{t}{10}\right)\left(20\sin(\frac{t}{10} )+ 51\right)$$
Now we just apply the condition $t=100$
$$E'(100)= 4\cos\left(10\right)\bigg(20\sin(10 )+ 51\bigg)$$
Now we note that $\color{red}{\text{IN DEGREES}}$ this is a little under $\$215$, but we always work in radians in calculus... if we calculate this in radians we get $\color{red}{\approx -134.65}$. This matches our predictions; the slope is decreasing. Since the question asks how fast it is decreasing we take the absolute value to get $\color{red}{\approx 134.65}$

Comment: oh my! thank you!!! this is why i don't seem to get it right.. I never though of changing it to radians.

Comment: @marg_ocruz Sure thing :) Don't worry... it happens to he best of us from time to time XD I honestly realized that you probably used degrees when I checked my work and was confused because Wolfram Alpha (a site that does basic algebra and calculus) was returning answers in degrees!!